# Where to store GAE / Google Cloud SQL database credentials?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I'm setting up a PHP application using Google App Engine and Cloud SQL. I have it running, but was wondering where should I securely store the database credentials PHP uses when connecting to Cloud SQL.

I currently keep the credentials in a PHP file that I "require_once" whenever I need to connect to the database. The file that contains the credentials is not listed in the app.yaml, so I don't think it can be accessed, but I'm not sure as I'm new to Google App Engine.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Best practice would suggest you store them "in the environment" and not in your code - because they vary between deployment environments (dev vs live)

For App Engine you can define environment variables in the app.yaml, or in an "included" yaml file, or on the command line when deploying.

I realise this is a lot of input.

Read this:
http://12factor.net/config

Good luck!

Comment: Storing db credentials in `app.yaml` which by design is supposed to be accessible by developers / debuggers is a very bad idea, equivalent to hardcoding them in code - stealing those credentials is very easy.